# How to determine if foreach loop has found 0 results

Tags: c#

I've got a program that runs a `foreach` loop, running a method for each file it finds in a directory. (Logs what file number it's currently, also running a method on that file)

I was wondering what would be a smart method of returning a '0' result if the `foreach` loop has found no files in the loop.

This is probably something easy to achieve but I'm a little confused at the moment...

Here is how I am running my loop.

```
int count = 1;
Log("| ", true);
Log("| Looping For Specific Criteria...", true);

// Loop through all files for condition
foreach (string fullFileName in FileList)
{
    // Run a method and report a result..
    count++;
}
```

If the loop found nothing matching my criteria in this case, I would like to report "0 results found"

I've considered adding the following after my `foreach` loop...

```
if (count == 1)
{
    Log("0 results found");
}
```

But I have to start with 1 on when declaring my int value to get a log list like..

- 1) file method complete
- 2) file method complete

... and so on

I thought I could use my int value to determine if the count has changed but the problem with that is, the `count` integer always holds at least a value of 1 and running my if statement would also throw the "0 results found" message if there was only 1 file processed in the `foreach` loop.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why do you need to start with 1 instead of 0? Imho your problem is solved with: `int count = 0;`

Comment: You could return a negative value like -1 to indicate the absence of files.

Comment: ` if (count == 1){ Log("0 results found")}` ? You need to reevaluate you counter to be something more literal i think.

Comment: I think you are over thinking this... `log((count-1) + " results found");`

Comment: I probably could begin with a 0 value. I am writing over someone else's code though and for whatever reason, they began at 1 and that start the list at count 1. Would 0 begin my list count at 1 as well?

Comment: @codeman061988 C# like most C based languages is zero-indexed. It makes more sense to start loops at zeros because items inside collections will also start at zero

Comment: I fail to see what's wrong with your current code. you could set the initial value of `count` to anything, and then check if that gets increased...

Comment: I'll try starting at 0 to begin with for now, incrementing **before** I execute the method.

Comment: @Tim Schmelter good point. I hadn't taken indexing into consideration like I should have.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set your `count` variable to zero if you increment it ***before*** executing your method which displays the value.

```
int count = 0;

foreach (string fullFileName in FileList)
{
    count++;
    // Run a method and report a result..
}
```

If the loop does not execute, `count` will be at `0`, you can then proceed with a `count == 0` check.

If it executes, it will increment to `1` immediately and you'll have your "1) file method complete" message for the first element.

So basically your count starts at 0, but your list will still start at 1 as you need.

Comment: This is going to work for my solution. Others have clever suggestions as well. I just need a rule to determine if the count has changed.

Answer (score 11):

**This is most certainly not the only way to do things, but I think it is the most idiomatic that clearly indicates your intention. Code should be written for the programmer primarily, and only the compiler if optimization is required.**

In addition to above suggestions, instead of using a for loop, you can utilize LINQ and do

```
if(!FileList.Any())
{
   ....
}
```

In order to keep with your requirements..

```
If the loop found nothing matching my criteria in this case, I would like to report "0 results found"
```

You can utilize `.Where`

```
var fileList = yourSource.Where(x => SomeFunctionThatSatisifiesYourRequirements(x));
// check to see if there are any elements, if not, report it and exit the function
// this is more idiomatic than checking an incremental variable IMO
if(!fileList.Any())
{
    Console.WriteLine("No results found");
    return;
}
// iterate over each element
// if there are none we won't reach this point
// and even if we do get here with no elements
// the for loop expands into nothing anyway
foreach(var element in fileList)
   YourFunction(element);
```

You want to replace `SomeFunctionThatSatisifiesYourRequirements` with a function that does your requirement-checking. It needs the signature `bool FunctionName(string fileName)`. `yourSource` would also need replacing. I'd do this for you but your code in your question does not give me much to go on :(

Finally, I'd like to note that the OP's question was "How do I determine if a foreach loop has found 0 results", and the best way to do this is to check whether the thing you are iterating over has 0 results before doing the foreach loop - `IEnumerable.Where(predicate).Any()` is the most idiomatic way to do this. You can also do `IEnumerable.Any(predicate)` if you don't care to use the filtered `IEnumerable`. The only reason I would consider using any other approach would be

- I have to compare two numerically-indexable sequences in place at the same time
- I have to apply some complex transformation to the data inside the loop before working out if the element is valid for processing (in which case, I would use an approach similar to yours currently, using `continue` to skip over the invalid elements)

I've set this as community wiki in case anyone wants to add edits or further clarify for the OP

Comment: There may be some blowback because it doesn't address the actual loop problem(s) but I'm upvoting because this solution is something people searching for this question should see.  Also .Any() is a very good short circuit.

Comment: I appreciate that it doesn't use the for loop but imo if you are checking for the presence of an element in an Enumerable (which OP seems to be), `.Any()` is much more idiomatic than `FileList.Count > 0`. An enumerator-based for loop won't have any iterations executed if there are no elements, and so it doesn't make sense to enter a loop to check for the presence of elements in the thing you are enumerating

Comment: Agreed, but bear in mind that the poster is also (supposedly) calling a method to report what files were found.  You might want to address that requirement also.  In really shorthand: `if(FileList.Any()) foreach(var f in FileList) Console.WriteLine("{0}) Found file '{1}'",FileList.IndexOf(f), f); else Console.WriteLine("Found 0 files.");`

Comment: The OP is asking about whether or not a certain requirement is matched within a list of files. I'll update my post to match these requirements

Comment: OP mentioned that he is _"running a method for each file it finds in a directory"_, so the count is just a side product. However, `Enumerable.Any` is fine anyway since it doesnt "cost" anything in this case, but it increases readability.

Comment: That's true, but he is also saying that if there are no files found, he wants to report it to the user. Therefore the best approach would be (as I've specified in post) to check the presence of files, if none report it and return, otherwise proceed with your method code.

Comment: I like this suggestion but true, I am running a method on each.

Comment: @codeman061988 Updated OP, please check to see how you could run teh method on each

Comment: As I said I'm trying to do what you're doing but in a more idiomatic way. This is most certainly not the only way but it communicates the intention very clearly (We should probably take this to a chat)

Comment: @Dan Pantry Not ignoring your post by any means. This method will also work as well for certain situations. I tried this as well and it was successful. I will incorporate this into my existing class to handle the list it's self.

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't you set your count to 0 initially?

`int count = 0` instead of `int count = 1`

```
if (count == 0)
{
     Log("0 results found");
}
```

This is why you're always showing that a file exists, even when there are no files.

Comment: Hah, you beat me by seconds, my alter ego :)

Comment: This has to be a StackOverflow first, amazing! I had to refresh the page, thought something was wrong.

Comment: I probably could begin with a 0 value. I am writing over someone else's code though and for whatever reason, they began at 1 and that start the list at count 1. Would setting my int value to 0 begin my list count at 1 as well?

Comment: Actually, you're code should still work if you're looking for a 1 value to indicate no files. I looked at your code quickly and experience told me that the initial value of 1 was wrong.

Comment: That's what I ended up doing. I am also going to increment before running my method in the `foreach` loop.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your problem is simple...

You start the count at 0.  Then in the foreach statement, before you process and log you do the increment.

Like this:

```
int count = 0;
Log("| ", true);
Log("| Looping For Specific Criteria...", true);

// Loop through all files for condition
foreach (string fullFileName in FileList)
{
     count++
     // Now run the method Run a method and report a result..
}

if (count == 0) //This can now safely be 0 as you only increment if there is a file
{
     Log("0 results found");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's usually not a good idea to use one variable for several purposes. In your case, 'count' is already used for your log file. You may use it for the flag purpose you described too but in 2 months you have forgotten why it is initialized with 1 and the possible side effects you described.

However i think the way you wanted to use the count variable will work. Even if there is only one file in FileList, the value of count will be 2 after the foreach-loop because count is incremented within the foreach und therefore

```
If (count==1)
```

will evaluate to false. It will only be 1 if the loop was never executed.

Because of what i said before i recommend to use another boolean variable which is initialized with false before the loop and set to true within the foreach loop.

Comment: The problem I have with his code is that it only makes sense if you think about what the code is doing, rather than what the code says it is doing. As I mentioned in my answer, the code should be written for the programmer, mainly, and should only be written for the compiler if optimization is required. In other words, it should be obvious to the programmer by looking at the code what that code is intending to do.

Comment: @DanPantry, I agree with your comments: `the code should be written for the programmer`, but OP's code is clear enough for me, and I do like to do work in one `for loop` if I can (I know `Any()` will return from the first instance, but to me still...), may be it's just my problem :)

Comment: It took a bit of thinking for me to get his code, but I was spoiled by Ruby for a long time :) But when you think about it - you're doing a for() loop and then checking to see if the for() loop had any elements to work with - wouldn't it make more sense to do it the other way around? It's like kicking down a door and then checking to see if the key you had would fit afterwards

Comment: @DanPantry, I would say, I'm doing a for() loop and then checking if I have done any work... and your suggesting is about checking if there is any work to do, then do the work (it's fine if there is no work to do, but if there is, you double checked :P) But I have to say all these are minor and opinion based..

Comment: You may also argue that for logging you only want to log things which really happened. If you write your log before the loop and than some magic happens to the FileList...

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question, I once used a scripting language (ERPLN 4GL) with a neat SELECT syntax to fluently run code on database queries

```
SELECT | Actual query that defines which table fields are selected.

SELECTDO | Operation(s) that are executed for each selected record.

SELECTEOS | Operation(s) that are executed after the last record was selected.

SELECTEMPTY | Operation(s) that are executed in case no record was selected.

SELECTERROR | Operation(s) that are executed in case an error has occurred.

ENDSELECT
```

So you cound do this

```
SELECT * FROM products
WHERE product.category = 5
SELECTDO
    product.discontinued = 1
SELECTERROR
    message("Something went wrong")
SELECTEMPTY
    message("No products found")
ENDSELECT
```

I always missed something in NET, but after reading this post I put together a small helper class which can be used this way

```
        var items = new[] { 1, 2, 3}.AsEnumerable();
        items.ForEach(x =>
        {
            if (x == 3) throw new ArgumentException("3 is a bad number");
            Console.WriteLine(x.ToString());
        }).OnError(ex =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }).IfEmpty(() =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Empty");
        }).Execute();
```

Here is the code

```
public static class EnumerableExtensions
{
    public static ForEach<T> ForEach<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable, Action<T> body)
    {
        return new ForEach<T>(enumerable, body);
    }

}

public class ForEach<T>
{

    private IEnumerable<T> enumerable;

    private Action<T> forEach;
    private Action<Exception> onError;
    private Action ifEmpty;

    public ForEach(IEnumerable<T> enumerable, Action<T> forEach)
    {
        this.enumerable = enumerable;
        this.forEach = forEach;
    }

    public ForEach<T> OnError(Action<Exception> onError)
    {
        this.onError = onError;
        return this;
    }

    public ForEach<T> IfEmpty(Action ifEmpty)
    {
        this.ifEmpty = ifEmpty;
        return this;
    }

    public void Execute()
    {

        try
        {
            var isEmpty = true;
            foreach (var obj in enumerable)
            {
                isEmpty = false;
                forEach(obj);
            }
            if (isEmpty && ifEmpty != null)
                ifEmpty();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if (onError != null)
                onError(ex);
            else
                throw ex;
        }

    }
}
```